# ActiveMQ Artemis Client libraries with HornetQ server

Tags: hornetq, activemq-artemis

Is it possible to connect to HornetQ server using ActiveMQ Artemis client libraries (1.5.x or 2.x)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis has kept compatibility with HornetQ in that HornetQ *clients* can connect to an ActiveMQ Artemis *broker*. Compatibility has also been maintained so that newer ActiveMQ Artemis clients can connect to older ActiveMQ Artemis brokers. However, there's no tests that cover ActiveMQ Artemis clients connecting to a HornetQ broker. It *may* work, but there's no guarantee. The recommendation would be to simply continue using HornetQ clients to connect to HornetQ brokers.

Comment: We tried connecting HornetQ client to Artemis server and had copious errors. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2784  Using the same version on both sides is my recommendation.

Comment: FWIW, the ActiveMQ Artemis test-suite has compatibility tests with clients from HornetQ 2.3.5 and 2.4.7.

Comment: We were on hornetq-core 2.2.7.Final